# Get all the values of form fields having same ng-model in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new in angularjs and making a dynamic form fields with `ng-repeat` and all my fields having the same `ng-model`

My Code:

```
<form name="dataset" class="md-inline-form" novalidate>
     <div ng-repeat="column in columns">
        <input type="hidden" name="column_name" ng-model="dataset.columnName" value="{{column}}">
        <label for="">Column: <strong>{{column}}</strong></label>
        <div layout="column" layout-gt-xs="row">
             <md-input-container flex>
                 <label>Select Type</label>
                 <md-select name="type" ng-model="dataset.type" required>
                      <md-option value="string">String</md-option>
                       <md-option value="numeric">Numeric</md-option>
                  </md-select>
                  <div class="errors" ng-messages="dataset.state.$error">
                   <div ng-message="required">Required</div>
                  </div>
             </md-input-container>
        </div>
    </div>
    <md-button type="submit" ng-click="SavevalidateColumns()" class="md-raised md-accent" aria-label="Submit">Validate Now</md-button>
 </form>
```

Now i just want to get the values of my all dynamically created fields in my controller. Can any one help me regarding this ?

Comment: this.dataset in controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use my code.

```
<form name="dataset" class="md-inline-form" novalidate>
     <div ng-repeat="column in columns">
        <input type="hidden" name="column_name" ng-model="dataset.columnName" value="{{column}}">
        <label for="">Column: <strong>{{column}}</strong></label>
        <div layout="column" layout-gt-xs="row">
             <md-input-container flex>
                 <label>Select Type</label>
                 <md-select name="type" ng-model="dataset.type" required>
                      <md-option value="string">String</md-option>
                       <md-option value="numeric">Numeric</md-option>
                  </md-select>
                  <div class="errors" ng-messages="dataset.state.$error">
                   <div ng-message="required">Required</div>
                  </div>
             </md-input-container>
        </div>
    </div>
    <md-button type="submit" ng-click="SavevalidateColumns(dataset)" class="md-raised md-accent" aria-label="Submit">Validate Now</md-button>
 </form>
```

First You have to pass data in funciton.

Your controller code:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('moduleName', [])
            .controller('myCtrl',
                    function ($scope) {

                        $scope.SavevalidateColumns = function (dataset) {
                            var colName = dataset.columnName;
                            var type = dataset.type;
                            console.log(colName + "::::" + type);
                        };

                    });
})();
```

You have to inject this module into app also.